# Can someone recognize this game from a laptop commercial?

Tags: game-identification

I know it's a long shot, but if someone knows this game, it would be awesome.

Recently I was watching TV and a commercial clip for a laptop popped up with this game on. It looks like something that I want to try (a casual gamer here), but they did not mention the name or anything related to the game.

I managed to find the commercial online and cropped the image. Here it is:

[image: Game screen, blue/cyan interface, showing a score of '7,800']

Comment: Could you also link the commercial? It *could* help us identify the game.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The game is [Halo: Spartan Assault](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/halo-spartan-assault/9wzdncrfhwfh) (or maybe [Halo: Spartan Strike](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/halo-spartan-strike/9wzdncrfjbfj)).

<strike>The size of that picture is too low to find a definite answer but it is from either one of those. Both games looks like this:</strike> The map is green-er on Spartan Strike, so that screenshot is from Halo: Spartan Assault. Here is a screenshot from the PC version of the game ([mobile](http://betanews.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/wp_ss_20130718_0001.jpg) and [Xbox versions](https://cdn0.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/2804702/Halo_Spartan_Assault_Xbox_One_Co-op_Screenshot_02.1386870249.jpg) have some UI differences):

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: @Tyronne happy to help :)

Comment: Note: this isn't really a casual game, more like a twin stick shooter set in the Halo world.

Comment: I had a feeling this looked kind of like Halo, but I completely forgot about the mobile Halo games.

Comment: @Nzall It's still pretty casual, unless you want to 100% it. Just playing through the story isn't very hard.

Comment: What's the number at the bottom?

Comment: @KritixiLithos the score counter.